# I cannot use Android Studio with Flutter because of bad file indexing

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

## Context

I'm using Flutter with VS Code for a while, but I want to switch to Android Studio.
My project is a Flutter "Module", which is embed in a Android App, this work well for few years.

## Problem

When I import my project in Android Studio, all my files are yellow because of non-indexation.
[image]

If I want to run the project, I can see this error in the configuration screen (bottom) : [image]

## Hint ?

If I create a new flutter project, and then I paste all my files, it works and I can run my project. BUT when I restart the IDE (or Invalidate cache), the problem comes back.

I dont understand what causes this, maybe something override my settings and delete my indexing ?

#### Flutter Doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81 darwin-arm64, locale fr-FR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

#### What I have done

Everything I fount on Internet

- Invalidate Cache
- Keep the .iml files, and paste them in the project
- Delete .idea folder, .iml files
- Using the tool inside Android Studio to repair the project
- Recreating the project and paste all files (this trigger the "Hint ?" part of my explanation : it works until I restart the software)

### Update !

I tried to create a blank new project, and adding my files 1 by 1 (it was terrible). After each file added, I restarted the IDE. The goal was to find THE file which was responsible of the non-indexation

And this file was the `build.gradle.kts, and more globally the gradle configurations. I think Android Studio is lost because of Gradle. What is the best thing to do now ?

Here is the `build.gradle.kts` file (without private informations)

```
// when changing the Flutter version, don"t forget to also upload the dependencies generated by the aar to the GAR with dependency-build.gradle

import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import phraseapp.phraseapp

   
fun garToken() : String {
    val fis = FileInputStream("${project.rootDir}/.secure/properties/gradle.properties")
    val prop = Properties()
    prop.load(fis)
    return prop.getProperty("GAR_TOKEN")
}

fun phraseToken() : String {
    val fis = FileInputStream("${project.rootDir}/.secure/properties/gradle.properties")
    val prop = Properties()
    prop.load(fis)
    return prop.getProperty("PHRASE_TOKEN")
}


fun versionName() : String {
    val fis = FileInputStream("${project.rootDir}/gradle.properties")
    val prop = Properties()
    prop.load(fis)
    return prop.getProperty("VERSION_NAME")
}

val flutterVersion = "1.0.0-a794cf2681c6c9fe7b260e0e84de96298dc9c18b"
val dependenciesVersion = "23.12.01-02"


repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41")
        classpath("com.decathlon.phrase:phrase-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta01") 
    }  
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.70"
    `maven-publish`
}

apply {
    plugin("com.company.phraseapp")
}


phraseapp {
    val token = phraseToken()
    platform.set(phraseapp.internal.Platform.FLUTTER)
    authToken.set("token $token")
    projectId.set("xx")
    mainLocaleId.set("xx")
    resFolders.set(arrayListOf("res"))
}

tasks.register<Task>(name = "resolveDependencies") {
    group = "Build Setup"
    description = "Resolve and prefetch dependencies"
    doLast {
        rootProject.allprojects.forEach {
            it.buildscript.configurations.filter(Configuration::isCanBeResolved).forEach { it.resolve() }
            it.configurations.filter(Configuration::isCanBeResolved).forEach { it.resolve() }
        }
    }
}


publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("debug") {
            groupId = "com.company.flutter.project"
            artifactId = "debug"
            version = versionName()
        
            artifact("$buildDir/host/outputs/repo/com/company/project/flutter_debug/1.0/flutter_debug-1.0.aar")
            
            pom.withXml {
                // hack to manual add dependencies
                val root = asNode()
                val dependenciesNode = root.appendNode("dependencies")

                fun addDependency(groupId: String, artifactId: String, version: String, scope:String) {
                    val dep = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency") 
                    dep.appendNode("groupId", groupId)
                    dep.appendNode("artifactId", artifactId)
                    dep.appendNode("version", version)
                    dep.appendNode("scope", scope)
                }

                addDependency("io.flutter", "flutter_embedding_debug", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "armeabi_v7a_debug", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "arm64_v8a_debug", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "x86_64_debug", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "x86_debug", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("dev.fluttercommunity.plus.device_info", "device_info_plus_debug", 
                dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider", "path_provider_debug", dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core", "firebase_core_debug",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics", "firebase_analytics_debug",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.remoteconfig", "firebase_remoteconfig_debug",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics", "firebase_crashlytics_debug",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.performance", "firebase_performance_debug",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("net.nfet.flutter.printing", "printing_debug", dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("com.jrai.flutter_keyboard_visibility", "flutter_keyboard_visibility_debug", dependenciesVersion, "compile")

                root.appendNode("description", "Flutter module for xx")
                root.appendNode("inceptionYear", "x")
            }
        }
        create<MavenPublication>("release") {
            groupId = "com.company.flutter.project"
            artifactId = "release"
            version = versionName()

            artifact("$buildDir/host/outputs/repo/com/company/project/flutter_release/1.0/flutter_release-1.0.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                // manually add dependencies
                val root = asNode()
                val dependenciesNode = root.appendNode("dependencies")

                fun addDependency(groupId: String, artifactId: String, version: String, scope:String) {
                    val dep = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency") 
                    dep.appendNode("groupId", groupId)
                    dep.appendNode("artifactId", artifactId)
                    dep.appendNode("version", version)
                    dep.appendNode("scope", scope)
                }

                addDependency("io.flutter", "flutter_embedding_release", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "armeabi_v7a_release", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "arm64_v8a_release", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter", "x86_64_release", flutterVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("dev.fluttercommunity.plus.device_info", "device_info_plus_release", dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider", "path_provider_release", dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core", "firebase_core_release",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.analytics", "firebase_analytics_release",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.remoteconfig", "firebase_remoteconfig_release",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics", "firebase_crashlytics_release",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.performance", "firebase_performance_release",dependenciesVersion, "compile")
                addDependency("net.nfet.flutter.printing", "printing_release", dependenciesVersion, "compile") 
                addDependency("com.jrai.flutter_keyboard_visibility", "flutter_keyboard_visibility_release", dependenciesVersion, "compile")

                root.appendNode("description", "Flutter module for xx")
                root.appendNode("inceptionYear", "x")
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://xx")
            credentials {
                username = "_json_key_base64"
                password = garToken()
            }
            authentication {
                create<BasicAuthentication>("basic")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a flavor configuration on the project?

Comment: @DonAriasAgokoli Nop, it's a fresh new project

Comment: please, can you share the contents of the main file?

Comment: I cannot because it's privacy code. But it cannot impact my problem of IDE .. It's a configuration problem, not about the code itself

Answer (score 0):

I fount a solution, making the folder root of the sources
[image: screenshot]

But, each time I launch IDE I need to click again ..